# In Play, how to copy js files from ScalaJS client to server?

Tags: scala.js, playframework-2.6, scalajs-bundler

I'm trying to write an app that's part ScalaJS and part Play framework. I'm using the [ScalaJS bundler](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler). It's bundling my JavaScript fine and I can see the resulting files where they are supposed to go.

[image]

But I noticed that only `client-jsdeps.js` and `client-fastopt.js` are available to the app. The reason for that is that their are the only files that are copied to the path `server/target/web/public/main`. I have looked everywhere I could think, `sbt` build files, config files, everywhere, and I could not find why those files are copied over and no other. I'd like the `-bundle` files to be copied instead. Where is that setting?

It is worth noting that the two files that are packaged with the app do not appear in the user-editable path, `server/public/js`, they are copied directly to the WAR file and therefore visible in the `target` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/getting-started.html#sbt-web):

For sbt-web integration use the `sbt-web-scalajs-bundler` plugin instead of `sbt-scalajs-bundler`:

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-web-scalajs-bundler" % "0.13.1")
```

Then, enable the `WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin` on the project that uses sbt-web:

```
lazy val server = project
  .settings(
    scalaJSProjects := Seq(client),
    pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline)
  )
  .enablePlugins(WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

lazy val client = project.enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin, ScalaJSWeb)
```

You also need to setup the `ScalaJSBundlerPlugin` on the Scala.js project, as described in the preceding section, and
the `sbt-web-scalajs` plugins as described in [their documentation](https://github.com/vmunier/sbt-web-scalajs).

The `WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin` plugin automatically configures the `scalaJSPipeline` task to use
the bundles rather than the output of the Scala.js compilation.

You can see a complete example [here](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/tree/master/sbt-web-scalajs-bundler/src/sbt-test/sbt-web-scalajs-bundler/play).

---

Do you follow that guide?

Comment: I had found it, but I had problems with parts of it earlier on the page and had not gotten to that part. Also, there are many guides, but that is the only one that mentions `WebScalaJsBundlePlugin`, so it was easy to overlook. I found it now and the bundles are included. Thanks!